# How to make a portable app (jar+sqlite) in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, jdbc

I made a tiny Java app (yes, tiny, 2 forms and a SQLite database) with Eclipse. It works when I run it in Eclipse.

I'll try to export it, and to make it a portable app (and put in an usb-key), but nothing works.

Here's my code to connect database:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+this.dbName);
DatabaseSQLite ConnBDD = new DatabaseSQLite("BDD/bdd.sqlite")
```

What must I change?

Here's my schema under Eclipse

```
[projects]
src
|-class
lib
|-sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar
BDD
|-database.sqlite
```

Comment: 'but nothing works' - what **exactly** does not work when starting the app?

Comment: (oups) the connexion between App and database...

Answer (score -1):

When i was doing it, i had done like this:

First, put sqlite3.exe into folder src/main/resources - now sqlite3.exe will be in jar-file as resource file. Then, copy sqlite3.exe (from JAR) into system32 (if it is windows and sqlite not installed):

```
// Copy file SQLite3 into /Windows/System32
try {
    // CopyFromJar just copies file from JAR archive into some directory
    CopyFromJar fileManager = new CopyFromJar();
    fileManager.copyFile(new File("C:\\Windows\\System32\\sqlite3.exe"), "/sqlite3.exe");
} catch (IOException e) {
    ErrorFrame.showException(e);
}
```

Second, add sqlite-jdbc as dependency to project. 
And last, create connection to database:

```
// Path to database - if first time, then database.db will created in folder with program 
private static final String pathToDatabase = "jdbc:sqlite:database.db";

//..................

// Loading JDBC driver
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

// Create connection
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(pathToDatabase);
Statement stat = con.createStatement();
```

Comment: vote down ? not me, but it doesn't work... (jar and database side by side, or database in a folder 'BDD')...

Comment: `code` public boolean connect ()
    {
        try
        {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database.sqlite");
            requete = connection.createStatement();
             
            requete.executeUpdate("PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;");
            requete.setQueryTimeout(30);
            return true;
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            // message = "out of memory" 
            MsgBox.ShowMessage("PB");
            return false;
        }
    } `code`

Comment: tested with Linux Mint but not with windows, perhaps... ?

Comment: problem with export config ? or schema config ?

Comment: I don't see 

Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

If program doesn't work then should be thrown exception. Which exception throws you program?

Comment: https://www.wuala.com/longuetgaylord/workspace/GestCyberSamer/src/BDD/?key=XZEXt4mtSlo9

Comment: Try to change path to database. I mean, [code] connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:CyberSamer.sqlite");[/code]
And run jar from folder with database. Is it works?

Comment: no success...    It's a problem with the path, when i create the jar with 'connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/home/user/Bureau/BDD/CyberSamer.sqlite");', it works...

Comment: I made it (test with Linux) !!  I use the Jar'Path and bingo...      connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile()+"CyberSamer.sqlite");